# Equals(=) vs. LIKE

Tags: sql, performance, equals, sql-like

When using SQL, are there any benefits of using `=` in a `WHERE` clause instead of `LIKE`?

Without any special operators, `LIKE` and `=` are the same, right?

Comment: Might want to specify a db type ... mssql, mysql, oracle?

Comment: Your question has at least `5` votes for the [tag:like-operator] tag. Could I kindly request that you suggest [tag:sql-like] as a [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/like-operator/synonyms)?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, I will do that when I get enough reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 364, accepted):

## Different Operators

`LIKE` and `=` are different operators. Most answers here focus on the wildcard support, which is not the only difference between these operators!

`=` is a comparison operator that operates on numbers and strings. When comparing strings, the comparison operator compares *whole strings*.

`LIKE` is a string operator that compares *character by character*.

To complicate matters, both operators use a [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-general.html) which can have important effects on the result of the comparison.

## Motivating Example

Let us first identify an example where these operators produce obviously different results. Allow me to quote from the MySQL manual:

> Per the SQL standard, LIKE performs matching on a per-character basis, thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator:

```
mysql> SELECT 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
+-----------------------------------------+
| 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       0 |
+-----------------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
+--------------------------------------+
| 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    1 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Please note that this page of the MySQL manual is called *String Comparison Functions*, and `=` is not discussed, which implies that `=` is not strictly a string comparison function.

## How Does `=` Work?

The [SQL Standard § 8.2](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt) describes how `=` compares strings:

> The comparison of two character strings is determined as follows:
>
> a) If the length in characters of X is not equal to the length
> in characters of Y, then the shorter string is effectively
> replaced, for the purposes of comparison, with a copy of
> itself that has been extended to the length of the longer
> string by concatenation on the right of one or more pad
> characters, where the pad character is chosen based on CS. If
> CS has the NO PAD attribute, then the pad character is an
> implementation-dependent character different from any
> character in the character set of X and Y that collates less
> than any string under CS. Otherwise, the pad character is a
> <space>.
>
> **b) The result of the comparison of X and Y is given by the
> collating sequence CS.**
>
> c) Depending on the collating sequence, two strings may
> compare as equal even if they are of different lengths or
> contain different sequences of characters. When the operations
> MAX, MIN, DISTINCT, references to a grouping column, and the
> UNION, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT operators refer to character
> strings, the specific value selected by these operations from
> a set of such equal values is implementation-dependent.

(Emphasis added.)

What does this mean? It means that when comparing strings, the `=` operator is just a thin wrapper around the current collation. A collation is a library that has various rules for comparing strings. Here is an example of [a binary collation from MySQL](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/strings/ctype-bin.c):

```
static int my_strnncoll_binary(const CHARSET_INFO *cs __attribute__((unused)),
                               const uchar *s, size_t slen,
                               const uchar *t, size_t tlen,
                               my_bool t_is_prefix)
{
  size_t len= MY_MIN(slen,tlen);
  int cmp= memcmp(s,t,len);
  return cmp ? cmp : (int)((t_is_prefix ? len : slen) - tlen);
}
```

This particular collation happens to compare byte-by-byte (which is why it's called "binary" — it doesn't give any special meaning to strings). Other collations may provide more advanced comparisons.

For example, here is a [UTF-8 collation](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/strings/ctype-utf8.c#L8241) that supports case-insensitive comparisons. The code is too long to paste here, but go to that link and read the body of `my_strnncollsp_utf8mb4()`. This collation can process multiple bytes at a time and it can apply various transforms (such as case insensitive comparison). The `=` operator is completely abstracted from the vagaries of the collation.

## How Does `LIKE` Work?

The [SQL Standard § 8.5](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt) describes how `LIKE` compares strings:

> The <predicate>
>
> `M LIKE P`
>
> is true if there exists a partitioning of M into substrings
> such that:
>
> i) A substring of M is a sequence of 0 or more contiguous
> <character representation>s of M and each <character
> representation> of M is part of exactly one substring.
>
> ii) If the i-th substring specifier of P is an arbitrary
> character specifier, the i-th substring of M is any single
> <character representation>.
>
> iii) If the i-th substring specifier of P is an arbitrary string
> specifier, then the i-th substring of M is any sequence of
> 0 or more <character representation>s.
>
> **iv) If the i-th substring specifier of P is neither an
> arbitrary character specifier nor an arbitrary string specifier,
> then the i-th substring of M is equal to that substring
> specifier according to the collating sequence of
> the <like predicate>, without the appending of <space>
> characters to M, and has the same length as that substring
> specifier.**
>
> v) The number of substrings of M is equal to the number of
> substring specifiers of P.

(Emphasis added.)

This is pretty wordy, so let's break it down. Items ii and iii refer to the wildcards `_` and `%`, respectively. If `P` does not contain any wildcards, then only item iv applies. This is the case of interest posed by the OP.

In this case, it compares each "substring" (individual characters) in `M` against each substring in `P` using the current collation.

## Conclusions

The bottom line is that when comparing strings, `=` compares the entire string while `LIKE` compares one character at a time. Both comparisons use the current collation. This difference leads to different results in some cases, as evidenced in the first example in this post.

Which one should you use? Nobody can tell you that — you need to use the one that's correct for your use case. Don't prematurely optimize by switching comparison operators.

Comment: "EQUALS compares two pieces of data byte by byte": oversimplified, and too often not true, because EQUALS (=) behavior can be modified with COLLATE, causing character classes to be compared instead of characters. E.g. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html (MySQL) or http://sqlmag.com/blog/forcing-collation-where-clause-22-jun-2011 (SQL Server).

Comment: @mehase this can't be true. If my varchar field contains the value `'AbCdEfG'`, and I do `WHERE MyCol = 'abcdefg'`, I still get that row back, even though they are clearly not byte-by-byte equivalent

Comment: PeterB and @Kip both raise good points. I've improved my answer to try to explain how collation affects these operators.

Comment: This doesn't seem true anymore: `set charset latin1;` `SELECT 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;`gives 0, and `SELECT 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;`gives 0 too.

Comment: So if the query search coming from a form, may or may not contain a wildcard, is it better to search the string for a wild card and build the query string rather than just defaulting to LIKE?

Answer (score 188):

The equals (=) operator is a "comparison operator compares two values for equality."  In other words, in an SQL statement, it won't return true unless both sides of the equation are equal.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Store WHERE Quantity = 200;
```

The LIKE operator "implements a pattern match comparison" that attempts to match "a string value against a pattern string containing wild-card characters."  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Name LIKE 'Chris%';
```

LIKE is generally used only with strings and equals (I believe) is faster.  The equals operator treats wild-card characters as literal characters.  The difference in results returned are as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Name = 'Chris';
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Name LIKE 'Chris';
```

Would return the same result, though using LIKE would generally take longer as its a pattern match.  However,

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Name = 'Chris%';
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Name LIKE 'Chris%';
```

Would return different results, where using "=" results in only results with "Chris%" being returned and the LIKE operator will return anything starting with "Chris".

Some good info can be found [here](http://www.firstsql.com/tutor2.htm).

Comment: I'm under the impression that the OP knows when to use LIKE and when to use =, he's just wondering if there is a performance difference when there's no wildcard present.  This answer briefly touches upon this but I feel that 95% of this answer is not really relevant.

Comment: Very true.  I'm not sure if the question was the same when I answered it.  If it was, I did miss the part which asked about the performance.  Thanks for the observation.

Comment: This answer is terrible. LIKE and '=' are completely distinct operators, but just happen to behave similarly in some small subset of cases. For the sake of posterity, please read the rest of the replies here, or at least google for "mysql like" before you commit this to memory.

Comment: On the other hand, this answer answered the question I had and googled for. Sometimes it's just as good if an answer answers the title of a question, as the content.

Comment: A good think to remember is when you are using char and varchar2.

If you compare char with char. Before compare the database first convert the length of first 'variable' to the same of second.

If you compare char and varchar2 the database will do nothing.


https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A64702_01/doc/server.805/a58236/c_char.htm

Answer (score 33):

This is a copy/paste of another answer of mine for question [SQL 'like' vs '=' performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142235/sql-like-vs-performance/28609481#28609481):

A personal example using mysql 5.5: I had an inner join between 2 tables, one of 3 million rows and one of 10 thousand rows.

When using a like on an index as below(no wildcards), it took about 30 seconds:

```
where login like '12345678'
```

using 'explain' I get:

[image]

When using an '=' on the same query, it took about 0.1 seconds:

```
where login ='12345678'
```

Using 'explain' I get:

[image]

As you can see, the `like` completely cancelled the index seek, so query took 300 times more time.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for exposing the results with high populated tables, explains and considering indices, this was really useful as well

Comment: @suarsenegger yes, big tables change everything

Answer (score 22):

`LIKE` and `=` are different. `LIKE` is what you would use in a search query. It also allows wildcards like `_` (simple character wildcard) and `%` (multi-character wildcard).

`=` should be used if you want exact matches and it will be faster.

[This site explains `LIKE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)

Answer (score 16):

One difference - apart from the possibility to use wildcards with LIKE - is in trailing spaces: The = operator ignores trailing space, but LIKE does not.

Comment: While this is true for MySQL and MS SQL, this isn't for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 11):

Depends on the database system.

Generally with no special characters, yes, = and LIKE are the same.

Some database systems, however, may treat collation settings differently with the different operators.

For instance, in MySQL comparisons with = on strings is always case-insensitive by default, so LIKE without special characters is the same. On some other RDBMS's LIKE is case-insensitive while = is not.

Comment: Is there something like an overview for this oddity?

Answer (score 9):

For this example we take it for granted that varcharcol doesn't contain `''` and have no empty cell against this column

```
select * from some_table where varcharCol = ''
select * from some_table where varcharCol like ''
```

The first one results in 0 row output while the second one shows the whole list. = is strictly-match case while like acts like a filter. if filter has no criteria, every data is valid.

like - by the virtue of its purpose works a little slower and is intended for use with varchar and similar data.

Answer (score 7):

Using = avoids wildcards and special characters conflicts in the string when you build the query at run time.

This makes the programmer's life easier by not having to escape all special wildcard characters that might slip in the LIKE clause and not producing the intended result. After all, = is the 99% use case scenario, it would be a pain to have to escape them every time.

*rolls eyes at '90s*

I also suspect it's a little bit slower, but I doubt it's significant if there are no wildcards in the pattern.

Answer (score 6):

If you search for an exact match, you can use both,  = and LIKE.

Using "=" is a tiny bit faster in this case (searching for an exact match) - you can check this yourself by having the same query twice in SQL Server Management Studio, once using "=", once using "LIKE", and then using the "Query" / "Include actual execution plan".

Execute the two queries and you should see your results twice, plus the two actual execution plans. In my case, they were split 50% vs. 50%, but the "=" execution plan has a smaller "estimated subtree cost" (displayed when you hover over the left-most "SELECT" box) - but again, it's really not a huge difference.

But when you start searching with wildcards in your LIKE expression, search performance will dimish. Search "LIKE Mill%" can still be quite fast - SQL Server can use an index on that column, if there is one. Searching "LIKE %expression%" is horribly slow, since the only way SQL Server can satisfy this search is by doing a full table scan. So be careful with your LIKE's !

Marc

Comment: -1 as no, it's not always a tiny bit faster.  If the column is indexed using %mystring% is a couple of orders of magnitude slower. Indeed any code standards worth their salt will have rigorous guidelines on when and when not to use like on any larger than a micky mouse database.

Comment: I never said it would be a tiny bit slower for all cases - I said it will be a tiny bit slower if you search for an EXACT match.
Of couse, searching with a LIKE and using wildcards, especially on the beginning and end of your search item, is MUCH slower, no doubt about that.

Comment: And yes, I agree - one *should* have clear guidelines as to when to use LIKE or not (only when you NEED to search with wildcards). But then again - in theory, there's no difference between theory and practice, but in practice.......

Answer (score 6):

To address the original question regarding performance, it comes down to **index utilization**.  When a simple table scan occurs, "LIKE" and "=" are **identical**.  When indexes are involved, it **depends** on how the LIKE clause is formed.  More specifically, what is the location of the wildcard(s)?

---

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    txt_col  varchar(10) NOT NULL
)
go

insert test (txt_col)
select CONVERT(varchar(10), row_number() over (order by (select 1))) r
  from master..spt_values a, master..spt_values b
go

CREATE INDEX IX_test_data 
    ON test (txt_col);
go 

--Turn on Show Execution Plan
set statistics io on

--A LIKE Clause with a wildcard at the beginning
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
SELECT txt_Col from test where txt_col like '%10000'
--Results in
--Table 'test'. Scan count 3, logical reads 15404, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 15416, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
--Index SCAN is 85% of Query Cost

--A LIKE Clause with a wildcard in the middle
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
SELECT txt_Col from test where txt_col like '1%99'
--Results in
--Table 'test'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3023, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 3018, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
--Index Seek is 100% of Query Cost for test data, but it may result in a Table Scan depending on table size/structure

--A LIKE Clause with no wildcards
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
SELECT txt_Col from test where txt_col like '10000'
--Results in
--Table 'test'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
--Index Seek is 100% of Query Cost
GO

--an "=" clause = does Index Seek same as above
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
SELECT txt_Col from test where txt_col = '10000'
--Results in
--Table 'test'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
--Index Seek is 100% of Query Cost
GO


DROP TABLE test
```

There may be also negligible difference in the creation of the query plan when using "=" vs "LIKE".

Answer (score 5):

`=` is much faster than `LIKE`.

Tested on MySQL with 11GB of data and more than 10 million of records, the f_time column is indexed.

`SELECT * FROM XXXXX WHERE f_time = '1621442261'`    - took 0.00sec and return 330 records

`SELECT * FROM XXXXX WHERE f_time like '1621442261'` - took 44.71sec and return 330 records

Answer (score 4):

Besides the wildcards, the difference between `=` AND `LIKE` will depend on both the kind of SQL server and on the column type.

Take this example:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
  varchar_name VARCHAR(10),
  char_name CHAR(10),
  val INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO testtable(varchar_name, char_name, val)
    VALUES ('A', 'A', 10), ('B', 'B', 20);

SELECT 'VarChar Eq Without Space', val FROM testtable WHERE varchar_name='A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'VarChar Eq With Space', val FROM testtable WHERE varchar_name='A '
UNION ALL
SELECT 'VarChar Like Without Space', val FROM testtable WHERE varchar_name LIKE 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'VarChar Like Space', val FROM testtable WHERE varchar_name LIKE 'A '
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Char Eq Without Space', val FROM testtable WHERE char_name='A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Char Eq With Space', val FROM testtable WHERE char_name='A '
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Char Like Without Space', val FROM testtable WHERE char_name LIKE 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Char Like With Space', val FROM testtable WHERE char_name LIKE 'A '
```

- Using [MS SQL Server 2012](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9586/2), the trailing spaces will be ignored in the comparison, except with `LIKE` when the column type is `VARCHAR`.
- Using [MySQL 5.5](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9586/2), the trailing spaces will be ignored for `=`, but not for `LIKE`, both with `CHAR` and `VARCHAR`.
- Using [PostgreSQL 9.1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9586/2), spaces are significant with both `=` and `LIKE` using `VARCHAR`, but not with `CHAR` (see [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html)).

  The behaviour with `LIKE` also differs with `CHAR`.

  Using the same data as above, using an explicit `CAST` on the column name [also makes a difference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4b92d/1):

  ```
  SELECT 'CAST none', val FROM testtable WHERE char_name LIKE 'A'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CAST both', val FROM testtable WHERE
      CAST(char_name AS CHAR) LIKE CAST('A' AS CHAR)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CAST col', val FROM testtable WHERE CAST(char_name AS CHAR) LIKE 'A'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CAST value', val FROM testtable WHERE char_name LIKE CAST('A' AS CHAR)
  ```

  This only returns rows for "CAST both" and "CAST col".

Answer (score 2):

Really it comes down to what you want the query to do.  If you mean an exact match then use =.  If you mean a fuzzier match, then use LIKE.  Saying what you mean is usually a good policy with code.

Answer (score 2):

The LIKE keyword undoubtedly comes with a "performance price-tag" attached.  That said, if you have an input field that could potentially include wild card characters to be used in your query, I would recommend using LIKE **only if** the input contains one of the wild cards.  Otherwise, use the standard equal to comparison.

Best regards...

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a ‘like’ with no wildcards will return the same result as an ‘equals’, but could require additional processing. [According to Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2668487300346354023), Oracle will treat a ‘like’ with no wildcards as an ‘equals’ when using literals, but not when using bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

`=` and `LIKE` is not the same;

1. `=` matches the exact string
2. `LIKE` matches a string that may contain wildcards (%)

Comment: It could be used without wildcards.The question asked the diffrence for the same cases.

Comment: = does NOT match exactly.   'x' = 'x '