# Analyze a string and determine an SQL operator

Tags: javascript, string

I need your help.

I'd like to write a function that would detect and determine the operator (LIKE/=) to use in an SQL string

Example:

```
var input_string = "SELECT * from table WHERE [FIRSTNAME]"

var input_text = document.GetElementbyId('firstname').value
```

if 1 of the 4 possible combinations are met from the given input_text then the operator value will be "LIKE", else it is an equal sign (=)

```
1.) At the start of the string:  %firstname

2.) somewhere in the string itself: first%name

3.) At the end of the string: firstname%

4.) at both ends of the string: %firstname%
```

Example:

```
var output_string = input_string + analyze(input_text) '+input_text+'
```

var output_string examples:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [FIRSTNAME] LIKE '%firstname%'
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [FIRSTNAME] LIKE '%first%name'
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [FIRSTNAME] LIKE 'firstname%'
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [FIRSTNAME] LIKE '%firstname%'
```

else

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [FIRSTNAME] = 'firstname'
```

Comment: You can just always use `LIKE`.  Doing `SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstname LIKE 'John'` should work fine.

Comment: A little off topic, why are you constructing SQL statements in JS? (curious).

Comment: I am making a simle HTA application to grab some info from an access DB and display it back to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want

```
function analyze(compare) {
    if (compare.indexOf("%") > -1)
        return "LIKE";
    else
        return "=";
    // or shorter with a regex and conditional operator:
    return /%/.test(compare) ? "LIKE" : "=";
}
var output_string = input_string+" "+analyze(input_text)+"'"+input_text+"'";
```

However, as @RocketHazmat mentioned in the comments, you could just use `LIKE` always and it would work like `=` when there are no percent signs in the string.

Comment: Using `=` is faster if you don't have wildcards. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559506/mysql-using-like-vs-for-exact-string-match

Comment: Is it? To cite paxdiablo, "*In a decent DBMS (e.g., DB2 :-), the DB engine would recognize that there were no wildcard characters in the string and implicitly turn it into an `=` version*". And that was 2009.

Comment: ... you know that phrase about assumptions :)... but anyway, speed difference even if DB does not check will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Since using like depends on having the `%` you should simply check for the `%` character within your string using indexOf method.

Example:

```
function useLike(input_text)
{
  return input_text.indexOf('%')>-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use `LIKE` regardless.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstname LIKE 'John'
```

Is a valid query.