# MySQL UPDATE Statement using LIKE with 2 Tables Takes Decades

Tags: mysql

can you please advise why such a query would take so long (literally 20-30 minutes)?
I seem to have proper indexes set up, don't I?

```
UPDATE  `temp_val_import_435` t1,
`attr_upc` t2 SET t1.`attr_id` = t2.`id` WHERE t1.`value` LIKE t2.`upc`


CREATE TABLE `attr_upc` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `upc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `upc` (`upc`),
 KEY `last_update` (`last_update`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=102739 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `temp_val_import_435` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `attr_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `translation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `source_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `core_value_id` (`core_value_id`),
 KEY `translation_id` (`translation_id`),
 KEY `source_value` (`source_value`),
 KEY `value` (`value`),
 KEY `count` (`count`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32768 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Ed Cottrell's solution worked for me. Using `=` instead of `LIKE` sped up a smaller test query on 1000 rows by a lot.

I measured 2 ways: 1 in phpMyAdmin, the other looking at the time for DOM load (which of course involves other processes).

DOM load went from 44 seconds to 1 second, a 98% increase.

But the difference in query execution time was much more dramatic, going from 43.4 seconds to 0.0052 seconds, a decrease of 99.988%. Pretty good. I will report back on results from huge datasets.

Comment: there is no column attr_id in tempval_import_435

Comment: hold on, that's a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=`?

Comment: @EdCottrell the query is on varchar columns which I thought should use `LIKE`

Comment: `=` should be much faster than `LIKE` -- `LIKE` is only for matching patterns, as in `'%something%'`, which matches anything with "something" anywhere in the text.

Comment: I found this question related to `LIKE` vs. `=`. I can try that simple change and see if it makes much of a difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559506/mysql-using-like-vs-for-exact-string-match

Comment: did you try using a netsted subquery instead of the join? may be better or worse depending on the size of your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `=` instead of `LIKE`.  `=` should be much faster than `LIKE` -- `LIKE` is only for matching patterns, as in `'%something%'`, which matches anything with "something" anywhere in the text.

If you have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where myColumn LIKE 'blah'
```

MySQL can optimize this by pretending you typed `myColumn = 'blah'`, because it sees that the pattern is fixed and has no wildcards.  But what if you have this data in your `upc` column:

```
blah
foo
bar
%foo%
%bar
etc.
```

MySQL can't optimize your query in advance, because it's possible that the text it is trying to match *is* a pattern, like `%foo%`.  So, it has to perform a full text search for `LIKE` matches on every single value of `temp_val_import_435.value` against every single value of `attr_upc.upc`.  With a simple `=` and the indexes you have defined, this is unnecessary, and the query should be dramatically faster.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting information. I would think the query optimizer could do a quick `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE myColumn LIKE '\%'` (or like `_`) to find out if it could optimize the end query with an `=` sign. But I guess it doesn't. I'll give this a try soon.

Comment: I tested it on a smaller data set with about 1000 rows. It took about 1 second with `=`, vs' about 44 seconds with `LIKE`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In essence you are joining on a LIKE which is going to be problematic (would need EXPLAIN to see is MySQL if utilizing indexes at all).  Try this:

```
UPDATE  `temp_val_import_435` t1
INNER JOIN `attr_upc` t2
  ON t1.`value` LIKE t2.`upc`
SET t1.`attr_id` = t2.`id` WHERE t1.`value` LIKE t2.`upc`
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. My version of MySQL does not support `EXPLAIN` on anything but `SELECT` statements, but I may upgrade soon. I do get the sense, though, that some sort of cartesian result is being processed. It should not take 17 minutes to update 30k records.

Comment: I think that MySQL may perform the same kind of join internally with my syntax as you use explicitly in yours. Either way, the queries take about 44 seconds with `LIKE` comparisons on fields, and about 1 second with `=`.