# What's the difference between "LIKE" and "=" in SQL?

Tags: sql, syntax, comparator

Is there any difference between:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="davyjones"
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE "davyjones"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equals(=) vs. LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like)

Comment: Here, the coming output is same but if i talk about the time consumption then where clause is take more time then the like clause if i imagine that this query is executing on a large data set.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As per SQL standard, the difference is treatment of trailing whitespace in CHAR columns. Example:

```
create table t1 ( c10 char(10) );
insert into t1 values ('davyjones');

select * from t1 where c10 = 'davyjones';
-- yields 1 row

select * from t1 where c10 like 'davyjones';
-- yields 0 rows
```

Of course, assuming you run this on a standard-compliant DBMS. BTW, this is one the main differences between CHARs and VARCHARs.

Comment: why would the second example yield 0 rows?  These two statememts look equivalent to me given your test data

Comment: because 'test' is stored as 'test' + 4 spaces. SQL standard says that LIKE should not match that, while = should. For VARCHAR columns there is no difference.

Comment: Yet another reason for never using char data type unless you will always have that exact number of characters.

Comment: @HLGEM -- who needed another reason?

Comment: What RDBMSs does this apply to? Doesn't make any difference in SQL Server

Comment: One extra case that may help understanding one of the differences : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715609/sql-server-automatically-strips-trailing-whitespace

Answer (score 49):

`LIKE` allows partial matching / use of wildcards, while `=` checks for exact matches.

For example

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE field LIKE '%oom';
```

Will return rows where field value is any of the following:

```
Zoom, Boom, Loom, Groom
```

Comment: It won't return those rows if column is CHAR(5) instead of VARCHAR(5).

Comment: @codeburger: MySQL has years before it gets anywhere near being SQL standard compliant ;)

Comment: @MilanBabuškov Its still nice to say it, MySQL is a free good DBMS for small projects!

Answer (score 13):

In that case, there is no difference that would come up in the results.  However, it uses a different method for comparision, and the "LIKE" would be much slower.

Check out this for examples of LIKE : http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

In this case, you still want to use the equals.

**Update**:  Note that there is a crucial difference when it comes to CHAR type columns in which the results **will** be different.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504990/whats-the-difference-between-like-and-in-sql/1505035#1505035) for more details.  When using VARCHAR (presumably the norm), the above are equivalent and equals is to be preferred.

Comment: Potentially in a stored procedure, however in testing in SQL Server through dynamic SQL, I've noticed it does not optimize this.

I've also run a test on Oracle, and it doesn't seem to optimize Dynamic SQL.

Comment: I find it amazing how wrong answers often get accepted on SO. :(

Comment: In what manner would you say that my answer is wrong?  In this situation, LIKE and '=' have identical functionality.  He really means '=', and thus should.  

I also pointed out a bit of documentation on how LIKE should be used...

Pretty sure I answered the question as much as everyone else.

Comment: See my answer below, and read up on SQL specs. There is an important difference if you use CHAR columns.

Comment: Ah, I knew of that difference, however I hadn't run into that in a while.  I made the assumption he was using VARCHAR, since I (and my company) tend to use it any time the data doesn't have a fixed length.

Answer (score 5):

```
create table A (id int,name varchar(30))

insert into A values(4,'subhash')
```

Use the trailing whitespace to search the name field:

```
select * from A where name='Subhash '
--Yields 1 row
select * from A where name like 'Subhash '
--Yields 0 row
```

Answer (score 4):

`LIKE` allows wildcards like `%` (any number of characters here) and `_` (one character here).

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'joe%'
```

Selects all usernames starting with `joe`.

Answer (score 3):

LIKE searches for a pattern.

```
/* Returns all users whose username starts with "d" */
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'd%'

/* Returns all users whose username contains "dav" */
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%dav%'
```

Answer (score 2):

That will give you the same result.  However, LIKE allows wildcards, for example...

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'davy%'
```

The only syntax problem was double quotes instead of single quotes

Answer (score 1):

[LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp) supports wildcards.  Usually it uses the % or _ character for the wildcard.

Using the LIKE operator with no wildcards is the same as using the = operator.

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` condition allows you to use wildcards:

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers
WHERE supplier_name like 'Hew%';
```

[See more examples.](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)

and Equals `=` is used for equality matching.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no difference but a time cost to the two selects you wrote. Usually one uses `LIKE` together with `%`, meaning 'any string'. I think there's also a character that can be used with `LIKE` for 'any character', not sure what that is without googling.

But as your two selects go, the only difference I see is a different run time, since `LIKE` is used in a regexp-sort-of-fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Like is pattern matching operator and `=` is exact matching operator. i.e. where name like `W%` it means start with `W` and after that one or more characters
and `=` i.e. where name `='James'` this is exact matching

Answer (score 0):

Equals `'='` is just for equality.  On the other hand, `LIKE` supports SQL wildcard matching.

So, with `LIKE` you can do `name like '%jones'` to get all the names ending in jones.  With `LIKE`, the percent `'%'` character is anything, length zero or more, and the underscore character, `'_'`, is any one character.

Answer (score 0):

`Like` gets you to work with wild card operators, you may use it in your case for `like 'davyjon%'` to get all the results starting with `davyjon`, and to get the exact you may place `'davyjones'` and you may also use `=` in this case

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is too old, but I get many others will try to find out the answer even nowadays. In many books, LIKE may come slower than '-' in most case, except when you want to compare String.