# SQL Server automatically strips trailing whitespace

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL WHERE clause matching values with trailing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166159/sql-where-clause-matching-values-with-trailing-spaces)

When querying SQL Server (through Management Studio Express for what its worth), I've noticed that when querying a `varchar` field it doesn't matter if you have some trailing whitespace in your criteria, it will still match.

The below matches `matched` (so it ignores the trailing whitespace in the search criteria)

```
select top 10 * from sometable
where somecolumn = 'matched    '
```

I've tried this on 2005 and 2012, same result.

Any ideas why this happens? Is it something to do with how `varchar` are stored?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4166186/284240

Comment: Does look to be but the tagging of that question ("C#, Database"!) means it didn't show up in title searches when writing the question.  Suggest re-tagging of the old question.  If someone that has permissions can do that please.  After that then this can be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

It is a normal behaviour : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626/

'like' doesn't follow that behaviour :

```
select top 10 * from sometable
where somecolumn like 'matched    '
```

will not return "**matched**"