# extra space in sql where condition issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using `SQL Server 2008 r2` and facing a problem while executing a select command.
Please look into the structure of my table(all column's datatype is nvarchar) :

```
employee  id      fname   lname
--------------------------------
abcdef    12345   Amit    Sharma
abcdeg    12346   Amit    Shar
```

when I try to query out with  following command

```
select * 
from userinfo 
where employee = 'abcdef   ' and id = '12345    '
```

It still gives me the result back.

I am not able to identify the problem.

Please suggest me anything that I can do to fix this.

Comment: "it still gives me the result back" ??what are you exactly expecting??

Comment: what is the problem here

Comment: hi chandru thanks for replying...i have edited the post... problem is when i try appending extra space in where condition

Comment: Hi NetStarter ...these where conditions comes from user input...and if appended extra spaces it should not return any result but still SQLSERVER ignores the extra space and return the result..

Comment: then why you dont use LIKE instead of = in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a valid point but it is according to SQL Standard you can read [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/string-comparison-functions.html) to find out what is the difference in **=** and **LIKE**,also [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504990/whats-the-difference-between-like-and-in-sql) answer on SO from Milan Babuškov
Hope it helps