# SQL Server query to match the exact word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, exact-match

This query returns the following:

```
select * 
from dbo.persons 
where LastName like '%Dan%';
```

Results:

[image]

How can I select only the first row with `LastName = "Dan"` and not "Dant" or "Dan12" ?

I am using the following query:

```
select * 
from dbo.persons 
where LastName like '%[^a-z]Dan[^a-z]%' 
   or LastName like 'Dan[^a-z]%' 
   or LastName like '%[^a-z]Dan'
```

which returns the following:

```
LastName = Dan12
LastName = pine and Dan and apple
```

I want only these results:

```
LastName = Dan
LastName = pine and Dan and apple
```

I tried the following query but it returned nothing:

```
select * 
from dbo.persons 
where LastName like '%[^a-z][^0-9]Dan[^a-z][^0-9]%' 
   or LastName like 'Dan[^a-z][^0-9]%' 
   or LastName like '%[^a-z][^0-9]Dan'
```

Comment: Use equals instead of `like` -- `where lastname = 'dan'` ...

Comment: Don't use like... use `=`. `Where LastName = 'Dan'`

Comment: Remove the % from your literal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "LIKE" and "=" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504990/whats-the-difference-between-like-and-in-sql)

Comment: Why is downvoted? Besides from he can google it. Its a questions which is pretty clearly.

Comment: @plaidDK - that's reason enough to downvote, as it shows a lack of research.

Comment: @user2366842 Youre right. I just hoovered over the wrong place. I can see now that downvote is when its for lacking of research efforts. Always thought it was due too lack of information :)

Comment: @plaidDK beside research the logic isnt clear. is just the Dan you are looking for or just the first one alphabetical

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
select * from dbo.persons where LastName ='Dan';
```

Comment: This solution does not work. It matches 'Dan ' (extra space at the end) also.

Comment: @TheImpaler You are very wrong here. `=` wont match any extra space. And the weird part is you also have the exact same query but you said Sami is the one wrong?

Comment: I can't believe what you are saying. Am I going crazy here? :D I have SQL Server 2014. I just tried and equals (=) return the 'Dan ' (extra space at the end). For the record, I tried to down vote my answer, but doesn't allow me to. What version of SQL Server are you using? Is your column `char` or `varchar`? Mine is `varchar`.

Comment: @TheImpaler extra spaces are ignored in equality operators in SQL Server so you aren't crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the statement below will do what you want:

```
select * from dbo.persons where LastName like 'Dan';
```

or:

```
select * from dbo.persons where LastName = 'Dan';
```

Comment: I'd arguably state the second of these two is better practice, as it's a bit more direct on exactly what you're looking to pull back.

Comment: for the sake of the argument, the second will return a row with value 'Dan  ', while the first will not :)

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I just tried both of them against 'Dan ' (extra space at the end), and to my surprise BOTH find it. I can't believe even equals (=) also matches the `varchar` column. Is this a SQL Server bug?

Comment: This is strange, are you sure? To my knowledge, = disregards trailing spaces, but LIKE doesn't.

Comment: Just tried both (like and equals). I tried with extra spaces at the beginning, at the end, and both places. The bug is for spaces at the end only. Please downvote my answer, and upvote the question.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following query that seems to work:

```
  select * from dbo.persons where LastName like '%[^a-z]Dan[^a-z]%' OR 
                                  LastName like 'Dan[^a-z0-9]%' OR 
                                  LastName like '%[^a-z]Dan' OR
                                  LastName like 'Dan';
```

These are rows that are returned which are expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to the following post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444300/search-for-whole-word-match-with-sql-server-like-pattern   This post helped me in framing this query.

Comment: You can mark this answer as correct so everyone know this is already solved.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have to wait for another day to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to guess you dont know which one is the first one so this doesn't work:

```
where LastName = 'Dan'
```

instead you select the first one order alphabetical

```
select TOP 1 * 
from dbo.persons 
where LastName like '%Dan%'
ORDER BY LastName ;
```

Comment: This solution does not work. It also matches 'Dan ' (extra space at the end).

Comment: @TheImpaler This solution works as I explain on the answer. You assume OP want `Dan` , I assume OP want the first row matching the where clausule.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The OP says 'Dan', which makes your A correct too.

Comment: @Sami OP want the first result matching the pattern. In this case is `Dan` but you dont know that before perform the query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `LIKE` which check any occurrence of a character or a set of characters by using the wildcard `%` use `=` to get the exact match you need.
If there will be a trailing whitespace at the beginning or at the end it will not get the exact match so use LTRIM() or RTRIM() to get rid of the whitespaces.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.persons WHERE LastName = LTRIM(' Dan')
```

OR

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.persons WHERE LastName = RTRIM('Dan ')
```

Comment: This solution does not work. It matches 'Dan ' (extra space at the end) also.

Comment: @TheImpaler i think it will not only work if there will be a space in the beginning , not at the end, if this will be the case then trim for the space at the beginning so it will still get the exact match