# Full Text Search Find Exact Word

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-mining, data-warehouse

I use full text search on my SynonymWords table. I need to find exact word.
I put my search word between quotes but it still to get result.
I expected there is no result. Where i do a mistake?

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM SynonymWords WHERE CONTAINS(Words,'"zebra"')
```

The result is here

[image: Full Text Search Result]

Answer (score 0):

Fulltext index doesn't work that way

it would find Zebra as long as there is a space or an interpunct before and behind it, so that ozt can idenitfy it a a word.

That's the function of the full text search and you can't change it.

A word like zebrajsduerhn would not be found by your query

You would change it to

```
SELECT * FROM SynonymWords WHERE CONTAINS( [words], '"zebra*"')
```

It taes some time to get used to it

Iyou want to have an exact search for word i would recoment to read this thread [SQL Server query to match the exact word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949736/sql-server-query-to-match-the-exact-word) which handles this and also have an answer for regular expressions.

If you need something faster you should take a look at elasticsearch and opensearch, but these needs also some time to undertsand the concepts