# What is the difference between "like" and "="?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the difference between "like" and "=" ?
For example:

```
  def sequence
    slug = title.to_param
    sequence = Movie.where("slug = '#{slug}-%'").count + 2
    "#{slug}-#{sequence}"
  end
```

and

```
  def sequence
    slug = title.to_param
    sequence = Movie.where("slug  like #{slug}-%").count + 2
    "#{slug}-#{sequence}"
  end
```

Comment: [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504990/whats-the-difference-between-like-and-in-sql), that's not a question strictly related to Rails.

Comment: @SebastianPalma several developers said me that using here "like" I can have SQL injections. Is it right?

Comment: Any query like this one where you interpolate user input directly into a SQL string is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. But that's really a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

"=" will return the exact match 
"LIKE" will return partial matching

sql injections can happen in both cases 
You need to do a sanity check on the inputs , use parametrized queries like : 
User.where("id = ?", params[:user][:user_id]).first

check
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

for "LIKE" operator specifecally a DOS attack could occur
check http://rorsecurity.info/portfolio/rails-sql-injection-like