# To write a query where it would extract the number of requests on various fields .

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Source Table]

> I want write a query which would give two columns :
>
> 1> Type of Query  2> Count
>
> This result set should have  following structure

[image]

> Here the 1st column values should be predefined and the count has to
>   be calculated . I want to check the Request column of source table and
>   find specific pattern . If that pattern is found increase the count .
>
> For Example :
>
> If there is a word "greenhopper" found in the request column then that
>   belongs to type GREENHOPPER .
>
> OR
>
> If there is a word "gadgets" found it is of the type DASHBOARD . and
>   so on ...
>
> So I want to analyze the usage of various categories by using the log
>   table .
>
> Hence Finally I can get the amount of usage and after that I can build
>   a pie chart out of it .
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'Greenhopper' AS TypeOfQuery, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM YourTable
WHERE Request LIKE '%Greenhopper%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dashboard', COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
WHERE Request LIKE '%gadgets%'
-- And so forth
```

You said they were predefined right? So you'd have ~10 different statements `UNION`'d together.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Requests AS
(
SELECT
CASE
WHEN Request LIKE '%Greenhopper%' THEN 'GreenHopper'
WHEN Request LIKE '%gadgets%' THEN 'Gadgets'
-- and so on
ELSE 'Misc'
END RequestType
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
RequestType,
COUNT(*) RequesCount
FROM Requests
GROUP BY RequestType
;
```

No data to test but I believe this approach will perform better as the table will be scanned less times. Performance is never going to be ideal though because of the LIKE and first wild card. This will prevent seeks.

Further explanation of why LIKE does not perform [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142235/sql-like-vs-performance)

Having just re looked at the question you may be able to improve performance further by changing the search string so it only has a wildcard on the right

e.g. LIKE 'GET /rest/gadget%' and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot this query works perfectly alrite . But when I use Microsoft Reporting Service to Display in Pie Chart it gives and error   ".5pt is not a valid unit designator Valid unit designators are in, mm ,cm,pt,pc" . Please can you help me with this too

Comment: Unsure what would be causing this, but I doubt it is related. Perhaps raise it as a new question and it will get more exposure. Just a thought though, is it possible to have .5 of a point?

Comment: Even I am confused. Any way Thanks a lot for your help