# SQL: How to perform string does not equal

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE tester <> 'username';
```

I am expecting this to return all the results where tester is not the string `username`, But this not working. I think I am looking for the inverse of the `Like` operator but I am not sure? In my searches I have found solutions for numbers (that's where i got <> from), but this seems to not be working with strings.

Comment: Are the values you are having problems with `NULL` values? (`NULL <> 'username'`  => `NULL` => false)?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Your `where` clause will return all rows where `tester` does not match `username` AND where `tester` is not null.

If you want to include NULLs, try:

```
where tester <> 'username' or tester is null
```

If you are looking for strings that do not contain the word "username" as a substring, then `like` can be used:

```
where tester not like '%username%'
```

Comment: keep in mind that "like" has performance costs
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142235/sql-like-vs-performance

Comment: I really wonder why the MySQL developers did not implement `!=` that you find in most of the programming languages today.

Comment: It was quite confusing checking column for != 'string' while having rows with NULL in column but with OR IS NULL it works

Answer (score 44):

Try the following query

```
select * from table
where NOT (tester = 'username')
```

Comment: This one doesn't include the null values in my case (postgresql)

Answer (score 27):

NULL-safe condition would looks like:

```
select * from table
where NOT (tester <=> 'username')
```

Comment: Yes!, this is the only thing that works for me, because I have a chain of and's. Didn't know the <=> operator. 
Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed that the `<=>` operator only exists in the `MySQL` world, for more info see [what is <=>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927117/what-is-this-operator-in-mysql)

Answer (score 8):

```
select * from table
where tester NOT LIKE '%username%';
```

Answer (score 7):

The `strcomp` function may be appropriate here (returns 0 when strings are identical):

```
 SELECT * from table WHERE Strcmp(user, testername) <> 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of getting the results

```
SELECT * from table WHERE SUBSTRING(tester, 1, 8)  <> 'username' or tester is null
```