# Flask-SQLAlchemy 'OR' query with variable number of parameters

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an advanced search interface that sends key:value pairs to my flask application.
The key is the column in the table to search and the value is the condition to compare against.

Below is a sample query for projects where k is the 'tags' column in the Projects table and v is the tag to search against.

```
projects = Projects.query.filter(getattr(Projects, k).like('%{}%'.format(v)))
```

If the user submits two tags to search against, v will be a list of the two tags.  I can then query the database like this:

```
if len(v) == 2:
    v1, v2 = v[0], v[1]
    projects = Projects.query.filter(or_(
        getattr(Projects, k).like('%{}%'.format(v1)),
        getattr(Projects, k).like('%{}%'.format(v2)))
    )
```

Is there a better way to perform the 'OR' query where the number of tags (in this example) is variable?

How can I write the code so it can handle 2 tags or 10 tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `*` expansion to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to `or_`.

```
or_filters = [getattr(Projects, k).like('%{}%'.format(term)) for term in v]
projects = Projects.query.filter(or_(*or_filters))
```

Keep in mind that using a large number of `LIKE` lookups in a SQL query is usually inefficient.

Comment: Amazing.  Instead  of LIKE, would a '==' query be more efficient?  Tags are being selected from a pre-defined list so an '==' query would work in this case.

Comment: This is a large enough topic to warrant [its own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142235/sql-like-vs-performance).