# select in sqlite3 failed

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I've defined schema like this

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE session(sid vchar(100) PRIMARY KEY ASC, msgid vchar(100), updated int(32), ip vchar(40), port int(32));
```

but there is no answer when i query the db use `select * from session when sid='xxxxx'`

for example

there is a row `SINKSESSIONID0153FD46440001|000000000000001542|1409109272|10.0.0.1|35963`

when i use `select * from session when sid='SINKSESSIONID0153FD46440001'`
it failed like this

```
sqlite> select * from session where sid = 'SINKSESSIONID0153FD46440001';
sqlite>
```

but when i use `select * from session when sid like 'SINKSESSIONID0153FD46440001'`
the right answer is returned

```
sqlite> select * from session where sid like 'SINKSESSIONID0153FD46440001';
SINKSESSIONID0153FD46440001|000000000000001542|1409109272|10.0.0.1|35963
```

i don't know why...

btw there is more than 50000 row in session

```
sqlite> select count(sid) from session;
57570
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Check this post, you can find some useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like

Comment: Try running REINDEX.

Comment: @CL. it doesn't work

Comment: Does it work with `select * from session where +sid='SINKSESSIONID0153FD46440001';`?

Comment: It looks like UPPER/LOWER case problem with COLLATE BINARY option in DB. Makes sure you query `when sid='SINK....` not for example `when sid='sINK...` (with lower case letters) in this case `sid='sINK` returns no rows but `LIKE 'sINK...` returns one row as expected.

Comment: @CL. it doesn't work either

Comment: @valex thx a lot but my query is all uppercase

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(sid) FROM session`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that some (all?) `sid` values in the database are blobs, not strings, so a comparison with a string will not match.
(LIKE does not make sense with blobs, so it automatically converts to strings.)

If the `sid` values are supposed to be blobs, you would have to compare them with a blob value.
In an SQL query, this could be done with a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue):

```
SELECT *
FROM session
WHERE sid = x'53494E4B53455353494F4E49443031353346443436343430303031';
```

If the `sid` values are supposed to be strings, you can fix the database with a command like this:

```
UPDATE session SET sid = CAST(sid AS TEXT);
```