# PHP to search SQL for exact and LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently using the below query;

```
SELECT * FROM '' WHERE Name LIKE 'argument'
OR Reg LIKE 'argument'
```

However, this will only show results that are `LIKE` `Name` or `Reg` not exact.

How do I change this query to search for results that are exact **and** like?

Comment: Remove the '%' symbol

Comment: If you only want to search for exact matches you can just remove `LIKE` and both `%` and replace it for `=` so it becomes `Name = '$searchq'`, when using the comparsion operator your query will execute faster. Read this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `%`. Try with -

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Name LIKE '$searchq' OR Reg LIKE '$searchq'
```

Answer (score 0):

or just use an equals operator for checking the Reg...

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE (Name LIKE ('%'. $searchq .'%') OR Reg = '$searchq')
```

Note: It may also be worth ensuring all letters in the Reg and search string are both upper case before doing the search. e.g.

```
 <%php $searchq = strtoupper($searchq); %>

 SELECT * FROM cars WHERE (Name LIKE ('%'. $searchq .'%') OR upper(Reg) = '$searchq'
```

Comment: Sorry, i had a typo in the query above - the % signs need to be in the LIKE part!

Comment: I've amended the second code section above.   The % signs should be around the search string only for the LIKE comparison.

Comment: For the exact match, you should do and =,  but you need to make sure that any letters in the data and the search string are converted to upper case.  Just for the purposes of the comparison, so no need to change the data permanently!

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
"SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Name = '$searchq' OR Reg = '$searchq'"
```

out of the option?

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL to this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Name LIKE '%".$searchq."%' OR Reg LIKE '%".$searchq."%' OR Name = '".$searchq."' OR Reg ='".$searchq."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I hope you are sanitizing your the search string. Not sanitizing it may leads to SQL Injection.

Comment: Case (Uppercase or Lowercase) may affect your results. Spacing may affect affect.

Check the value you are searching for if it's exactly the name.

Comment: You may seperate the names (firstname and lastname). But that shouldn't be affect your results.