# Search Some Text in Coumn (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if my question is a newbiew question :(

I just want to search some record that have some values of text.

Example, I have table like this: 
[image]

Can you write for me the query to find a record that contains 'Robot' in description column.

I don't want to use `LIKE` query.

Thanks all

Comment: So what exactly you need if not like? Any reason why you dont want like?

Comment: y dnt u want like? @ilham

Comment: Interesting to know you don't like like.

Comment: I thought LIKE cant find all text that i need, i/e %Robot% just can find 'Robot' text in the middle of  the text, not for the first or the end. So i was wrong, im new on mySQL. Sorry all and thanks for any help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are looking for LIKE :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE description LIKE '%Robot%'
```

If you don't want to use LIKE then:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable 
WHERE INSTR(description, 'Robot') > 0
```

Comment: Probably someone who thinks there's a better way than LIKE.

Comment: but, what if there is a Robot in the first of the statement, like this : "Robot is a .... ", you cant use LIKE %Robot% right?

Comment: So it will still be returned, % means that any thing can replace it(including nothing) any way i posted an answer without like

Comment: This answer is correct. I found a good discussion in case you want to find different ways of using SELECT statements with WHERE clauses using both 'like' and '=' operators. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/543740/4438391)

Comment: Can be improved, till return XYZRobototos rows as well.

Comment: And you know he don't want this row? @jarlh I can add space there but I don't know if this what he wants

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason not to use LIKE, but anyway:

```
SELECT * FROM sakila WHERE description REGEXP 'Robot'
```