# Indexing strange wildcard on SQL

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, rdbms, varchar

My query contains `LIKE "%BLABLA"`. Will it optimize my query if I add an index? If yes, will both clustered and unclustered B+Tree indexing improve my query?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. This is a product specific question!

Comment: I don't think a `LIKE` filter will be able to use anything coming after the wildcard during tree traversal.  So therefore I don't think an index would help in this particular query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like/39531185#39531185 they say it is possible for any other LIKE expressions

Comment: @Codevan Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm not sure that link is relevant.  The equals operator would not work for the query in the OP, so comparing it to `LIKE` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE 'abc'` is very similar to `= 'abc'`;
`LIKE 'abc%'` is a "range", which is likely to be able to us an index;
`LIKE '%abc'` cannot use an index - because of the *leading* wildcard.

If you would like to discuss what could be done for your query, please provide the entire query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the reversed data in another field, add an index on that reversed field and query against that reversed field.  Instead of using `LIKE '%abc'` you will use LIKE `'cba%'`, using the reversed field.