# Difference between SQL LIKE without percent signs and equal (=) in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Are there any differences in the results of these two queries other than performance?

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE 'Spot';
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name = 'Spot';
```

Reason I ask is the real script will be something like the following and the API user is responsible to come up with the pattern.  More often that not, a LIKE pattern will be provided, but there is always a chance that just a string will be provided resulting in `SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE "Spot"`.

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute([$_GET['name']]); //Spot
return [$stmt->fetchAll(),200];
```

Comment: If a DBMS is following Standard SQL there is a difference when there are trailing spaces, `name like 'Spot'` will not match `'Spot '`, but `=` will.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In *practice*, `LIKE` with no wildcards is functionally equivalent to `=`.  However, they are not the same!  The obvious difference is that `=` doesn't treat `\`, `%`, and `_` in any special way, but `LIKE` does.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) is pretty clear on this:

> Per the SQL standard, `LIKE` performs matching on a per-character basis,
>   thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator:

In addition to collation differences, trailing spaces matter:

> In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for
>   `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` comparisons performed with the = operator:

In practice, the strings being compared usually have the same collation, don't have trailing spaces, and special characters are ignored, so `LIKE` is sometimes used as a replacement for `=` (especially because `LIKE` without wildcards at the beginning of the pattern can also make use of an index).

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, it turns out to be the same thing in your example, but here is more info:

From [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like)

> = is a comparison operator that operates on numbers and strings. When comparing strings, the comparison operator compares whole strings.
>
> LIKE is a string operator that compares character by character.