# executeQuery() doesnt return any rows and the same statement returns row in sqlplus

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have used the select statement to get a record from sqlplus and the statement returned a row but when i use `executeQuery()` method in java it does not return any rows in resultset.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@LocalHost:1521:orcl","sys as sysdba","System_1");                                                                               
Statement stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);  
Resultset rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from server WHERE username='admin'");
```

p.s. :-I'm using oracle 12c

Comment: Please let us see your java code to that call

Comment: Is it connecting to the database succesfully?

Comment: YES it is connected to the database

Comment: Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@LocalHost:1521:orcl","sys as sysdba","System_1");
                                                                                                             Statement stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);                                   rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from server WHERE username='admin'");

Comment: Don't post code in comments [edit] your question.

Comment: Put you code in try catch block and look for exceptions. Or debug after creating connection.

Comment: it is already in try catch block

Comment: problem is in executeQuery() method

Comment: Paste your complete code so that we can help.

Comment: Please show some code how you process the result set, the comment on one of the answers suggests that you misunderstand what [`ResultSet.getRow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow--) returns (hint: it is not the total number of rows...)

Answer (score -2):

Try using LIKE keyword instead of =.

Comment: If `column LIKE 'admin'` would work, then so will `column = 'admin'`

Comment: @staszko032 refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like to know the difference between like and =