# Delete MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using PHP 7 and the latest mysql on ubuntu 16.10. This is the current code I have

```
<?php
        $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = 'password';
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    
        $sql = "DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE columnA LIKE '%Test7%'" ;
        mysql_select_db('jdbdev');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
        
        if(! $retval ) {
           die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        
        echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
        
        mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: it is not `columnA='%test%'` it is `columnA like '%test%'`

Comment: Your error is here. mysql_query takes two parameters. First one is your database connection, second is your query itself . as mysql_query($conn,$sql);

Comment: Thank you, still does not work as i also did try like

Comment: it's like not =

Comment: @PhpDev thank you but that also did not work

Comment: @Brigitte I am going to post some code in answer. Try it and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: also, are you 100% sure that your port is 3036 and not 3306(default)? remove the :3036 part and leave your host as 'localhost'

Comment: I tried without the both default port and without as well still not working.

Comment: @Brigitte add the or die after your connect. mysql_connect( 'host.name', 'user', 'password') or die('Could not connect to server.' ); Will it print 'could not connect to server'?

Comment: It connects and doest not print that, it gets to the retval and gives me could not delete data print out

Answer (score 0):

Should change to below query

```
DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE columnA like '%Test7%'
```

There is difference between `=` and `like` operator

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to delete all the rows where `columnA` contains the test "Test7", you need to use the `like` operator, not the `=` operator:

```sql
DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE columnA LIKE '%Test7%'
-- Here --------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use wildcard % then you have to use LIKE instead of =, so change your sql to:

```
"DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE columnA LIKE '%Test7%'"
```

Also, `mysql` functions are vulnerable to sql injection, you should use `mysqli` or even better `PDO` to manage your database.

Comment: Try setting your your host variable to localhost only: $dbhost = "localhost"

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE columnA = '%Test7%'" ;
```

should be **columnA like '%test7%'**

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE columnA like '%test7%'
```

Like and = both are [different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336940/2667307).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = 'password';
        $db_name = 'jdbdev';
        $conn = mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db_name);

        try{
         if($conn->connect_error){
          echo 'Could not establish connection to database because '.$conn->connect_error;
            }
        }catch(Exception $ex){
          echo $ex->getMessage();
          exit;
          }
           
         $sql =  "DELETE FROM databasetable WHERE databasetable.columnA LIKE '%Test7%'";
        $retval = $conn->query($sql);

        if($retval === FALSE) {
           die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        echo "Deleted data successfully\n";

        mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Sometimes, you have to reference the database table in front of the column

Comment: then the problem must be from your database connection.

Comment: I put if ! $conn print cannot connect but it seems to connect, i get the could not delete data error on retval

Comment: Thank you but now im getting blank screen, i also tried to add i mysqli

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear for me what you are trying to accomplish using this:

```
WHERE columnA = '%Test7%'" ;
```

Is the percent sign a literal that should match just like that? As you probably know, percentage sign is a wildcard in mysql and it should be use with LIKE rather than equal.

In this case, your condition will be:

```
WHERE columnA LIKE '%Test7%'`
```