# MySQL "LIKE" without "%" is not working same as "=" condition

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have the below MySQL query.

```
select * from node where title LIKE 'born in care shelter breed';
```

Which is returning empty set. But when I try the below query

```
select * from node where title = 'born in care shelter breed';
```

It is returning 1 result.

**What difference the both will make? I can't avoid the LIKE operator as the query creating after some condition checking**

Comment: Other possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like

Comment: which DB engine you are using and what is the characterset of table/column. Can you please add the table structure.

Comment: try this: `select * from node where trim(title) LIKE  trim('born in care shelter breed');` vs `select * from node where trim(title) =  trim('born in care shelter breed');`

Comment: @ADyson I updated my answer, had no idea about the trailing whitespace thing. Yes, I read the potential duplicates, obviously not thoroughly enough to see those bits. It's pretty hard to find in the MySQL doco. Thanks for informing me, you learn something new every day

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have trailing whitespace in your `title` field. MySQL string comparison using the `=` sign does not consider trailing whitespace. Note the following:

```
CREATE TABLE node
(title VARCHAR(99));

INSERT INTO node (title)
VALUES ('born in care shelter breed '); -- Note the space at the end

SELECT * FROM node WHERE title LIKE 'born in care shelter breed';
SELECT * FROM node WHERE title = 'born in care shelter breed';
```

Notice how the first select statement returns zero results, but the second one finds the row.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daba27/5)

The documentation talks about this on the [string comparison page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html), stating:

> In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for
>   CHAR or VARCHAR comparisons performed with the = operator

Answer (score -1):

The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.

There are two wildcards used in conjunction with the LIKE operator:

```
% - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters
_ - The underscore represents a single character
```

i think below will return row

```
select * from node where title LIKE '%born in care shelter breed%';
```

To know about [like](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) more

Comment: @Arun does it works?