# SQL count how much field from record is showed in other table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, the first one is USERS and the second one is TAGS.
this is the **USERS** table fields:

- ID
- NAME

and this is the **TAGS** table fields:

- PICTURE_ID
- USER_ID

now I want to count how much times one of the users  is "taged" in the TAGS table (both based on the user_id but I want to be able to check according to the name).

**example:**
if I have the user
**ID=1 NAME="aba"**
and in the TAGS I have
**PICTURE_ID=8 USER_ID=1,

PICTURE_ID=3 USER_ID=1.**
so the number of times "aba" is taged in pictures is 2.

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, COUNT etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(T.PICTURE_ID) AS TAGs_Count, U.NAME
FROM TAGS T
LEFT JOIN USERS U
ON U.ID = T.USER_ID
GROUP BY T.USER_ID, U.NAME
```

In case if you want to display counts just for specific User (here it's Aba)

```
SELECT COUNT(T.PICTURE_ID) AS TAGs_Count, U.NAME
FROM TAGS T
LEFT JOIN USERS U
ON U.ID = T.USER_ID
WHERE U.NAME LIKE 'Aba'
GROUP BY T.USER_ID, U.NAME
```

Or you can use wildcards if you don't know exact names you searching for:

```
WHERE U.NAME LIKE '%ba'
```

or

```
WHERE U.NAME LIKE 'Ab%'
```

or for both ends:

```
WHERE U.NAME LIKE '%b%'
```

If you want to have search case insensitive you use this:

```
WHERE UPPER(U.NAME) LIKE UPPER('Aba')
```

Also consider what operator actually you want to use.
LIKE and Equals ( = ) are not exactly the same.

More about that you'll find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like)

Comment: the count working but I want to give a name to count and not just print all of the users

Comment: Could you explain better what actually you want to get?

Both mine and Stu's scripts are giving you count of tags with the name associated to these counts.

Do you want to search for user ?

Comment: I want to write in the script the name of the user that I want to search for, for example if I want to get the count of "aba" so I write in the script to get me only the count of "aba"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple correlated aggregation here -

```
select u.Name, coalesce((select count(*) from Tags t where t.User_Id = u.Id),0) Tags
from Users u
where u.Id = 'aba';
```